# Cannot download new profiles for Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I have installed the Visual Studio emulator for Android, but I'm unable to install new device profiles, since it says that there is no internet connection. I'm writting this post from the computer that has this issue, so clearly I do have internet connection.

Here is a picture that shows the message:

[image]

Any ideas? I tried googling but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Can you access to http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt from that machine? May be a proxy/firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I investigated a bit and found the domain you mentioned blocked in my hosts file. I deleted the entry and now it works.